# RASA how to use Japanese (Tokennization-Mecab)

Tags: nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu, cjk, rasa-core

RASA is known to be an effective bots framework.
Stack such as RASA NLU and RASA Core is really useful.

I hand-on it around, I find out that its amazing especially with English text. I give another try on Japanese Text (Alpha support of spacy). I used it with tensorflow pipeline, I got stuck, I cannot figure out how to use external tokenization such as Mecab.

Anyone experience it ??

Answer (score 0):

The tensorflow pipeline works with any language that’s whitespace tokenized. As it is not the case with Japanse, you have to built your own tokenizer.

You can do so by extending the classes `Tokenizer` and `Component`, e,g.:

```
class MecabTokenizer(Tokenizer, Component):

# fill with your code
```

You can then use your custom class in your NLU pipeline by specifying the module path in the name ([also described in the docs](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/customcomponents/)), e.g.:

```
pipeline:
- name: "path.to.MecabTokenizer"
# other components
```

Somebody tried something similar [here](https://github.com/khut-pidor/RASA-Japanese), maybe you can use this or take is some sort of template.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a custom component using  Mecab tokenizer. It works fine for me for Japanese text.

Link: [Rasa_Japanese](https://github.com/mahbubcseju/Rasa_Japanese)